# How can I delete only the join table from a Many-to-Many bidirectional association?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have two tables, called "User" and "Group", with a Many-to-Many association mapped by a UserGroup join table, that has an extra column.
I have been able to list, add, and edit the association by saving either the user or the group, but I'm having a problem deleting the association (and only the association), i.e. removing a group from the user, or removing a user from the group, without deleting the group or the user. It seems hibernate does not execute a delete operation on the join table, despite removing the UserGroup from both sides of the association.

I have already looked at many stackoverflow questions with the same problem, and tried a bunch of different solutions (from [codenet](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example), [mkyong](https://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) and [Vlad Mihalcea's post](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/), for instance), but I can't figure out an easy way to delete the association in the join table simply by saving the Group or the User. In fact, not even creating a `UserGroupRepository` and directly calling `delete` does it, which leads me to believe my mapping is incorrect.

I tried using an `@EmbeddedId` and an `@IdClass`, but when I do it fails to add new or existing associations, complaining about 'detached entity passed to persist'.

I have created the following [Many to Many Mapping problem](https://github.com/TarekSaid/many-to-many-mapping-problem) example project, with GroupTest and UserTest integration tests verifying:

- new group or user's creation and association with existing users or groups (passes);
- associating a new user to an existing group / new group to an existing user (passes);
- changing the extra field from an UserGroup association (passes);
- removing a user from the group / removing a group from the user (fails).

Here's the failing test code:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class GroupTest {

    @Autowired
    private GroupRepository groupRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void deleteUserFromGroup() {
        // given that I have two users
        User u1 = userRepository.save(new User().setName("user 1"));
        User u2 = userRepository.save(new User().setName("user 2"));

        // and that I have a group with these 2 users
        Group group = groupRepository.save(new Group().setGroupName("test group").addUser(u1, true).addUser(u2, false));

        // when I delete user 2 from the group
        group.deleteUser(u2);
        group = groupRepository.save(group);

        // then the group should have 1 user
        assertThat(group.getUsers()).containsOnly(new UserGroup().setGroup(group).setUser(u1));

        // and user 2 should not have any groups
        assertThat(userRepository.findById(u2.getId()).map(User::getGroups).orElse(new HashSet<>())).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Here's the way I mapped the many to many and how I add or delete the association:

**Group (`DomainEntity` is a `@MappedSuperclass` that contains the `@Id` and other Group and User's common fields)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group extends DomainEntity {
    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String groupName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserGroup> users = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters omitted

    public Group addUser(User user, boolean active) {
        UserGroup userGroup = new UserGroup().setGroup(this).setUser(user).setActive(active);

        if (!users.contains(userGroup)) {
            users.add(userGroup);
            user.addGroup(this, active);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Group deleteUser(User user) {
        UserGroup userGroup = new UserGroup().setGroup(this).setUser(user);

        if (users.contains(userGroup)) {
            users.remove(userGroup);
            user.deleteGroup(this);
        }

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Group)) return false;
        Group group = (Group) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, group.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

**User has a similar `@OneToMany` mapping, equals, hashCode and addGroup/deleteGroup methods**

**UserGroup**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_group")
public class UserGroup implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class)
    private User user;

    @Column
    private boolean active;

    // getters and setters omitted

        @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof UserGroup)) return false;
        UserGroup userGroup = (UserGroup) o;
        return Objects.equals(group, userGroup.group) &&
            Objects.equals(user, userGroup.user);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(group, user);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need a `UserGroup` repository and delete from it directly since you are defining a `UserGroup` join entity.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I tried that, but calling the `delete(userGroup)` still doesn't delete it, which is why I think there's a mapping problem. I could use a custom `@Modifying @Query` with a deleteById, but it seems like a workaround...

Comment: There is no `UserGroup` repository so you do not have a reproducible example.

Comment: @K.Nicholas ok, I've updated the sample project adding a `UserGroupRepository` and two tests, one using `delete(userGroup)`, which fails, and another using the `deleteById(id)` @Query, which passes.

Comment: Yea, the `UserGroup` has its own ID. Use the `UserGroupWithEmbeddedId`. Either way, your test class is not using the UserGroupRepository so nothing will happen with that table since `User` or `Group` is not the owner of the relationship. Only the owner of the relationship can modify the join, in your case the `UserGroupWithEmbeddedId` entity.